# jProfiler long monitoring sessions

Tags: jprofiler

I'm using jProfilers for monitoring the activity and performance of a server in production. I've configured it in remote monitoring and it works ok, but for long monitoring sessions (I would like to do 24h monitornig) the amount of memory used by jProfiler keeps growing too much.

I would like to know if there is any better way to do 24h monitoring.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you see the increase in memory usage, in the profiled application or in the JProfiler GUI process?

Comment: In the JProfiler GUI process.

Comment: But I've reconfigured it and now the memory grows slowly. Now I can use it 24h and restart periodically. I've seen in the manual that there is a way to configure a trigger to dump the session periodically in a file, I've tried it but for the moment I've not been able to make it work properly.

Comment: OK, please write to support or create another question